# sum Time difference on records of same date

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

```
WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT *, 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonRFID ORDER BY DateStamp)
  FROM AISDb
where action = 'IN'
) ,
y As
(
  SELECT *, 
    rna = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonRFID ORDER BY DateStamp)
  FROM AISDb
where action='OUT'
) 

SELECT y.ID,x.ID,x.PersonName,y.PersonName,x.PersonRFID, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, x.TimeStamp, y.TimeStamp) 
FROM x , y      
where x.PersonRFID = y.PersonRFID
And x.rn=y.rna
AND  cast(x.Datestamp as date) = cast(y.Datestamp as date)
Order By x.PersonName;
```

I get the below table when i execute the above query:

```
   Datestamp         personName                     ID             TimeDifference

    1/30/2013   Aman Ullah Khan     E2001026770D01432810029D            11
    1/30/2013   Aman Ullah Khan     E2001026770D01432810029D            0
    1/30/2013   Aman Ullah Khan     E2001026770D01432810029D            1
    1/30/2013   Amjad Ali Anjum     E2001026770D024125401476            0
    1/30/2013   Amjad Ali Anjum     E2001026770D024125401476            1
    2/9/2013    Amjad Ali Anjum     E2001026770D024125401476            31
    2/10/2013   Amjad Ali Anjum     E2001026770D024125401476            3
    2/10/2013   Amjad Ali Anjum     E2001026770D024125401476            0
    2/10/2013   Amjad Ali Anjum     E2001026770D024125401476            3 
    1/30/2013   Arif Shah           E2001026770D01852370206D            0
    3/13/2013   Asmat Ullah         E2001026770D007624101DA1          456
    3/20/2013   Asmat Ullah         E2001026770D007624101DA1          558
```

As u can see for e.g for person name "amanullah khan" there are 3 records of same date i.e. 1/30/2013, But i need a single record that sums 'time difference' if dates are same and i should get

```
 1/30/2013   Aman Ullah Khan     E2001026770D01432810029D            14
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
SELECT  y.ID ,
            x.ID ,
            x.PersonName ,
            y.PersonName ,
            x.PersonRFID ,
            SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, x.TimeStamp, y.TimeStamp))
    FROM x
    JOIN y ON x.PersonRFID = y.PersonRFID
            AND x.rn = y.rna
            AND CAST(x.Datestamp AS DATE) = CAST(y.Datestamp AS DATE)
    GROUP BY y.ID ,
            x.ID ,
            x.PersonName ,
            y.PersonName ,
            x.PersonRFID
    ORDER BY x.PersonName
```

Comment: how it is different than mine?

Comment: Old-style join is deprecated (...from table1, table2...). Preferable use ANSI-style joins via JOIN. In all other no differences.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change as follows

```
 SELECT y.ID,x.ID,x.PersonName,y.PersonName,x.PersonRFID,sum(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, x.TimeStamp, y.TimeStamp))
FROM x , y      
where x.PersonRFID = y.PersonRFID
And x.rn=y.rna
AND  cast(x.Datestamp as date) = cast(y.Datestamp as date)
group by
y.ID,x.ID,x.PersonName,y.PersonName,x.PersonRFID
Order By x.PersonName;
```

Comment: I tried the above query, but got the same result as from the previous one (my query)....